# Increasing Speed of Bootstrapped Amplifier

Tags: amplifier, high-voltage, high-speed

I am trying to implement the design described [here](https://m.eet.com/media/1152270/24127-45890.pdf) to create an amplifier circuit that will amplify a 10MHz, 24Vpp signal to 120Vpp. I am using the [THS3062](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ths3062.pdf) op-amp, and originally I was looking at using the [2SC4883A](http://www.semicon.sanken-ele.co.jp/sk_content/2sc4883_ds_en.pdf) and [2SC1859A](http://www.semicon.sanken-ele.co.jp/sk_content/2sa1859_ds_en.pdf) transistors.  I am simulating my circuit in LTSpice using circuit models for all the parts, and found that it worked up to about ~50kHz. I tried replacing them with the [CZT5551](https://www.centralsemi.com/get_document.php?cmp=1&mergetype=pd&mergepath=pd&pdf_id=CZT5551.PDF) and the [CZT5401](https://www.centralsemi.com/get_document.php?cmp=1&mergetype=pd&mergepath=pd&pdf_id=CZT5401.PDF), and found that it worked up to ~300kHz.

I believe that the transistors are not fast enough, and since I have a higher voltage split supply, my transistors would need to have a high maximum Vce as well as a high speed. Is is possible to find a low-gain, high-speed, high-voltage transistor that will enable this circuit to work at higher speeds? Alternatively, could anyone recommend a modification to the circuit to make it work faster, or possibly an alternate circuit?

Here is my Spice schematic:
[image]

Comment: That bootstrapping article says plenty about bootstrapping, except speed. It's a clever technique, but there is a reason it's under-documented. 10MHz at 120V is hard. You would do better to design a more conventional all transistor power driver, then all the critical stuff is at your fingertips and not a few time constants away.

Comment: Fortunately, I don't need much current output from the amplifier - just higher voltages. I've never designed an amplifier at the transistor level, aside from the basic circuits taught in undergrad electronics - can you recommend a simple topology that would accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: At 10MHz with 120v swing, you *do* need a lot of current from the amplifier, to charge your output capacitance, including the inter-electrode capacitance of your output devices. Start with a push-pull pair of common-base (to reduce Miller) transistors, and get them slewing first. Then build cascode drivers under them, and work back.

Comment: This is all new to me - any recommendations as to where I can find some similar examples?

Comment: 10MHz amplifier design is hard, you're pushing the parasitics of devices the whole time, so it's going to be a whole new ball game for you. Start with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascode) for a discussion of the cascode stage, and then hit google once you've got the vocabulary. I was suggesting start with the output pushpull pair, as that's the most difficult bit, you need high voltage fast transistors, which is hard. Get them running in simulation to deliver your swing with ideal drive to them. Then work back to make the rest of the amplifier.

Comment: Although you might think that a low output impedance is useful, paradoxically when you need to drive a capaitive load (which is *any* load at high frequency) then a current drive into it works best. This means you grab the stability bull by the horns, accept 90 phase shift in the output stage, and make the rest of the amplifier deliver less than 45 degrees shift, which takes fast components, but with small voltage swings it's tractable. HF+HV design is one of the black arts that's not taught well in this digital age. Bob Pease (google) might have something to contribute in general.

Comment: Certainly an interesting approach - unfortunately, the device I am driving is an electro-optic device which operates in terms of the voltage applied across its terminals. Not sure how I would drive that with current, especially since capacitive loads block DC current

Comment: Do you know the impedance of your load? You could measure it with a network analyzer. It is essential to know it. If it is capacitive, Neil's idea will be an excellent choice... well, most likely the only choice ;)

Comment: I do know the impedance of the load - since transistors are inherently current amplifiers, would a push-pull and cascode system inherently be a current-drive amplifier?

Comment: What is the impedance of the load then? do you have a model? Indeed, if it is capacitive, and depending on its value, current-drive can be preferable, in this case the load capacitance is the amp's compensation cap, this is how LDO voltage regulators work.

Comment: You're not driving current into your electro-optic load, you're driving current into all the stray and device capacitances that you are stuck with hanging across your load, due to the fact that the circuit is built from wires with stray to ground, and devices with junctions which have capacitance, the feedback device you use to close the loop to control the output voltage. Your EO device will have a specified input capacitance as well.

Comment: Yes, the load model must include cable and parasitics...

Comment: Added an answer to be clearer about what I'm talking about. I could add more detail to the diagram if you're interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At 10MHz, and at 120v, how you shove current into all the capacitance of your load, and all the stray capacitance that lurks around, is critical. Let's guess at some figures. If you manage to achieve 100pF total load at your output node (your EO load, but including strays, cable, sockets, the output devices) and you want to slew that sinusoidally at 120vpp at 10MHz, you will need 60*100p*10M*2pi = 340mA, more if you want to approach something that looks more like a square wave. As your EO device is 10pF, you should be able to keep within 100pF, if you're careful.

You will need to use current drivers that are tame and predictable, and then close a fast feedback loop around them to control the output voltage.

As you are stuck with a minimum output capaitance which *will* create phase shift, the best plan is to incorporate that phase shift directly into your stability scheme. This is what LDOs do, while it's a different voltage regime it's the same stability problem.

The most difficult part is the output devices, as high voltage transistors tend to be slow. The smaller swings within the amplifier are easier to handle.

Here's a sketch of how the output might work. While you could use either bipolars or FETs for the high voltage common base (gate) devices Q1 and Q5, bipolars are probably better having a DC rated SOA and lower output terminal capacitance. You only need a few volts of bias across Q2 and Q6, set by the cascode bias voltages.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQw0cs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Choose R3/4 to give the desired gain at DC, choose C1/C3 to keep that voltage division going correctly to high frequency. You might want to put a small resistor in series with C3 to give some phase lead. Play with the components with SPICE, use a square wave input and try to get a small amount of tame overshoot on the transitions. Depending on the amplifier you choose, you may need additional phase lead components. Google for how LDOs do this sort of thing. Faster amplifiers and transistors will make getting stability easier.

Comment: Does this mean I can also use lower voltage transistors since there are multiple stacked in that fashion?

Comment: Q2/Q6 can be low voltage, operate them with a few volts Vce. Q1/Q5 will see the full output voltage thus need to be high voltage types. If we had any info on the load (hmm...) you could also use CRT drivers although they're obsolete...

Comment: Just got the model of device - they are [these](http://www.hanamuraoptics.com/device/EOSPACE/PC030123_EO.pdf), and in correspondence with the company they said the capacitance is ~10pF.

Comment: ... so you should be able to keep the total load under 100pF, with care

Comment: So if this is an output stage, with the feedback mechanism being marked on the diagram, where would the actual input be in a circuit like this? Additionally, you mention biasing Q2 and Q6, but in the diagram, Q1 and Q5 are noted as being biased. Can you describe the different biases a bit?

Comment: The bias voltage to Q1 would be a few volts above ground. Q1 emitter voltage is 0.7v below that, which 'puts a few volts of bias' on Q2. I'll add a bit more to the diagram to show the input. But bear in mind, I'm not designing this amplifier, you are, so I'm not adding anythign to the diagram that I will need to spend a long time designing.

Comment: Totally valid, your help is very appreciated! Is this amplifier considered a combination of push-pull (due to the configuration of the NPN and PNP transistors) and cascode (since there are two transistors of each type) or is it something entirely different?

Comment: it's a push-pull cascode, because that's what's in it. The basic amp I've dawn is class A, which means a lot of output device dissipation, you would want TO220 heatsinakble types, not the CZ... transistors you've mentioned in the OP. For lower dissipation, you'd have to figure out how to make it class AB or B. Lower load+stray capacitance = lower current drive needed to get the slew rate = lower output device dissipation.

Comment: +/-60V @ 10MHz into say 50pF will be 180mA peak, which results in quite high dissipation which will get in the way of picking really fast transistors... so it's going to be vital to minimize output capacitance, use very short cables or no cables... also any inductance between the amp and the load will modify the frequency response of course. Do you intend to use a cable? Is your signal capable of going through a transformer, btw?

Answer (score 0):

If the frequency is FIXED, then using resonance is the standard way to generate high voltages at high frequencies, because the parasitic capacitances become part of the solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, the frequency is not fixed - it can be as high as 10MHz.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at the opamp's inputs. If the output is at +60V, the opamp's supplies will be about +62 for the positive rail and +30V for the negative rail. This mildly exceeds the max rating, but is not the main problem...

The problem here is that the input signal which is 12V at this time is outside of the opamp's supply range, thus outside of the opamp's input common mode range!

Same problem for the feedback signal on the negative input, btw.

Therefore the opamp won't work. It might work in simulation if the opamp model is too simple, thus tricking you.

The article you quoted used a low gain and lower supplies, which ensured the signal would stay inside the proper range for the opamp's input stage to work...

Thus you can't make a bootstrap amplifier with a +/- 15V opamp to amplify 12V to 60V. You will need to roll your own... Complexity will depend a lot on requires output current, type of load, and required bandwidth (if the 10MHz signal is a square wave, you need a lot more than 10MHz bandwidth).

Comment: I believe the point of the feedback resistor (R8 in the schematic) is to solve this problem. As described by the article, "If you need greater gain from a single stage than the gain you can achieve with the circuit in Figure 1, then you may find the circuit in Figure 6 useful. In this configuration, VCM remains within the op amp’s input common-mode range, whereas VIN is much lower in magnitude (Figure 7)." The only difference between the circuit in Figure 1 and in Figure 6 is the inclusion of that resistor.

Comment: Hm, interesting, I had missed the positive feedback. I'd need to sim it. Also, THS3062 is current feedback which will be incompatible with the resistor values chosen...